# I'm having trouble with programmatically setting layout constraints in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I'm working on an iOS app which is a basic Pokedex, which will hopefully teach me the basics of working with UIKit (not using Storyboards for this project).  When I run my app everything lays out fine.  However when I scroll down there are some constraints that get messed up causing buttons to appear off screen.  I can't figure out what would be causing this to happen.  I think that some constraints are being applied or are not being applied when a cell is reused but I can't find an obvious error in my constraint code.

```
func set(pokemon: Pokemon) {
    name.text = pokemon.name
    var spriteName: String?

    if let pokemonForm = pokemon.form {
        addSubview(form)
        form.text = pokemonForm
        setNameLabelConstraints(hasForm: true)
        setFormLabelConstraints()
        switch pokemonForm {
            case "Mega":
                spriteName = String(pokemon.speciesID) + "-mega-sprite"
            case "Mega X":
                spriteName = String(pokemon.speciesID) + "-mega-x-sprite"
            case "Mega Y":
                spriteName = String(pokemon.speciesID) + "-mega-y-sprite"
            default:
                spriteName = String(pokemon.speciesID) + "-sprite"
        }
    } else {
        spriteName = String(pokemon.id) + "-sprite"
        form.removeFromSuperview()
        setNameLabelConstraints(hasForm: false)
    }
    sprite.image = UIImage(named: spriteName!)
    type1.setTitle(pokemon.type1, for: .normal)
    styleTypeFilterButton(button: type1)
    type1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    if let secondType = pokemon.type2 {
        addSubview(type2)
        type2.setTitle(secondType, for: .normal)
        styleTypeFilterButton(button: type2)
        setType2ButtonConstraints()
        setType1ButtonConstraints(twoButtons: true)
        type2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    } else {
        type2.removeFromSuperview()
        setType1ButtonConstraints(twoButtons: false)
    }

}

func setNameLabelConstraints(hasForm: Bool) {
    name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    name.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sprite.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    if hasForm == false {
        name.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        name.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        name.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = false
    }
}

func setType1ButtonConstraints(twoButtons: Bool) {
    //type1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if twoButtons == true {
        type1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: type2.leadingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
    } else {
        type1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
    }
}

func setType2ButtonConstraints() {
    //type2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    type2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
}

func setFormLabelConstraints() {
    form.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    form.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sprite.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    form.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    form.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: name.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    form.font = form.font.withSize(14)
}

func styleTypeFilterButton(button: UIButton) {
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 65).isActive = true
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = button.titleLabel?.font.withSize(14)

    switch button.titleLabel?.text {
        case "Normal":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "a8a878")
        case "Fighting":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "c03028")
        case "Flying":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "a890f0")
        case "Poison":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "a040a0")
        case "Ground":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "e0c068")
        case "Rock":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "b8a038")
        case "Bug":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "a8b820")
        case "Ghost":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "705898")
        case "Steel":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "b8b8d0")
        case "Fire":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "f08030")
        case "Water":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "6890f0")
        case "Grass":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "78C850")
        case "Electric":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "f8d030")
        case "Psychic":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "f85888")
        case "Ice":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "98d8d8")
        case "Dragon":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "7038f8")
        case "Dark":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "705848")
        case "Fairy":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "ee99ac")
        case "???":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "68a090")
        case "Shadow":
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "705848")
        default:
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexValue: "a8a878")
    }
}
```

[image: Initial view on page load]

[image: View after scrolling]

If someone could explain why it lays out correctly when the app first runs, but gets messed up after the cells get reused I would greatly appreciate it!  I've never worked with autolayout before, so I might also have in error in my autolayout code but I'm not sure if anything is wrong.  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: There's too much code here. You don't have to give every tiny bit of detail about your implementation like the pokemon switch case for title label and colour. You only need to post the relevant part. Take a look at [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some guesses about how your code works, but in short the problem is that you're not removing old layout constraints when you recycle your cells.

Let's say a cell gets created and for the first entry it has to display, you call `setType1ButtonConstraints(twoButtons: false)`. `type1` is now pinned to the trailing edge of the cell.  Then that cell is recycled and for the new entry it has to display you call `setType2ButtonConstraints()` and then `setType1ButtonConstraints(twoButtons: true)`.  Your code will pin `type2` to the trailing edge of the cell, and then pin `type1` to be before `type2`, but you never got rid of the constraint that was made from the first entry.  You now have a set of unsatisfiable constraints (there will be a warning about this in the console) and the system has to break one.

To solve this you should keep references to these constraints and remove them in `prepareForReuse()`.  You could also use a horizontal `UIStackView`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Keeping a reference and being able to activate / deactivate constraints was the solution to my problem